# Полноэкранный режим видео для веб-сайтов в браузере, PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qwebengineview, qwebenginefullscreenrequest

Делаю свой браузер для серфинга в Интернете.  Не могу настроить полноэкранный режим для видео. 
Например, нажимаю **`«полный экран»`** на *YouTube*, но ничего не происходит.

Я пытался решить проблему, но пока не получилось.  
Думаю, что смогу найти решение этой проблемы на этом форуме. 
Спасибо за помощь.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class FixedSizeTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


class SimpleBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.profile = QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()

        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_signals()
        self.setup_layout()

        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.load_page)

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Браузер(kennybloody)")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.profile = QWebEnginePage().profile()
        self.page = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, self)

        self.profile.setHttpCacheType(QWebEngineProfile.DiskHttpCache)
        self.profile.setPersistentStoragePath(QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.CacheLocation))

        self.page.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
        self.page.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
        self.page.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
        self.page.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
        self.page.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.Accelerated2dCanvasEnabled, True)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setPage(self.page)

        self.tab_widget = FixedSizeTabWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.add_tab()

        global_settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()
        for attr in (
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled,
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled,
        ):
            global_settings.setAttribute(attr, True)
        self.browser.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(self.FullscreenRequest)

        self.tab_widget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { min-width: 1px; max-width: 200px; text-align: left; }")

        self.url_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.url_entry.setText("")

        self.back_button = QPushButton("Назад")
        self.forward_button = QPushButton("Вперед")
        self.refresh_button = QPushButton("Обновить")

        self.back_button.setFixedWidth(40)
        self.forward_button.setFixedWidth(50)
        self.refresh_button.setFixedWidth(58)

        self.new_tab_button = QPushButton("Новая вкладка")
        self.new_tab_button.setFixedWidth(100)

    def setup_signals(self):
        self.url_entry.returnPressed.connect(self.load_page)
        self.page.urlChanged.connect(self.update_url_entry)
        self.new_tab_button.clicked.connect(self.add_tab)
        self.tab_widget.currentChanged.connect(self.update_current_tab)

        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.go_back)
        self.forward_button.clicked.connect(self.go_forward)
        self.refresh_button.clicked.connect(self.refresh_page)

        self.page.titleChanged.connect(lambda title: self.update_tab_title(self.tab_widget.currentWidget()))

    def setup_layout(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.back_button)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.forward_button)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.refresh_button)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.url_entry)
        horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.new_tab_button)
        horizontal_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        horizontal_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        layout.addLayout(horizontal_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget, 1)

    def add_tab(self):
        page = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, self)
        browser = QWebEngineView()
        browser.setPage(page)

        self.tab_widget.addTab(browser, "Вкладка")
        self.tab_widget.setCurrentWidget(browser)
        page.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))

        browser.setFocus()

        page.urlChanged.connect(lambda qurl: self.url_entry.setText(qurl.toString()))
        page.titleChanged.connect(lambda title, browser=browser: self.update_tab_title(browser))

        close_button = QPushButton("x")
        close_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent; border: none; color: red;")
        close_button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, browser=browser: self.close_tab(browser))
        self.tab_widget.tabBar().setTabButton(self.tab_widget.indexOf(browser), QTabBar.RightSide, close_button)

    def load_page(self):
        entered_url = self.url_entry.text()
        if not entered_url.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
            entered_url = 'http://' + entered_url

        current_browser = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
        current_browser.page().load(QUrl(entered_url))

    def update_url_entry(self):
        current_browser = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
        self.url_entry.setText(current_browser.page().url().toString())
        self.update_tab_title(current_browser)

    def update_current_tab(self, index):
        current_browser = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
        self.url_entry.setText(current_browser.page().url().toString())
        self.update_tab_title(current_browser)

    def update_tab_title(self, browser):
        index = self.tab_widget.indexOf(browser)
        if index != -1:
            title = browser.page().title()
            self.tab_widget.setTabText(index, title if title else "Вкладка")

    def go_back(self):
        current_browser = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
        if current_browser.page().history().canGoBack():
            current_browser.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Back)

    def go_forward(self):
        current_browser = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
        if current_browser.page().history().canGoForward():
            current_browser.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Forward)

    def refresh_page(self):
        current_browser = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
        current_browser.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Reload)

    def close_tab(self, browser):
        index = self.tab_widget.indexOf(browser)

        if self.tab_widget.count() > 1:
            browser.page().triggerAction(QWebEnginePage.Stop)
            browser.page().runJavaScript("var audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio'); audios.forEach(audio => audio.pause());")
            browser.page().runJavaScript("var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'); videos.forEach(video => video.pause());")
            self.tab_widget.removeTab(index)
            browser.deleteLater()
        else:
            self.hide()
            
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWebEngineFullScreenRequest")
    def FullscreenRequest(self, request):
        request.accept()
        if request.toggleOn():
            self.showFullScreen()
            self.browser.setParent(None)
            self.browser.showFullScreen()
        else:
            self.showNormal()
            self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
            self.browser.showNormal()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = SimpleBrowser()
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение состоит в том, чтобы установить `QWebEngineView` как центральный виджет.

`FullScreenRequested` — это сигнал, который отправляет запрос (`QWebEngineFullScreenRequest`),
который указывает, что какой-то ресурс (видео) хочет занять
весь `QWebEngineView` или хочет восстановиться до предыдущего состояния,
если он уже занимает весь `QWebEngineView`, 
но OP хочет ресурс, чтобы занять весь экран, что подразумевает,
что `QWebEngineView` занимает экран, поэтому для этого надо сделать: 
`setParent(None)` и `showFullScreen`, 
а в обратном случае нужно установить `QWebEngineView` центральным виджетом.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)                                   

        self.tbNavigate = QtWidgets.QToolBar(orientation=QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.tbNavigate)

        action_data = [
            ("Back", "icons/next.svg", self.browser.back),
            ("Forward", "icons/next.png", self.browser.forward),
            ("Reload this page", "icons/reload.png", self.browser.reload,),
            ("Home", "icons/home1.png", self.navigateHome),
        ]

        for text, icon_path, slot in action_data:
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(
                QtGui.QPixmap(icon_path), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off
            )
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(text, icon=icon, triggered=slot, parent=self)
            self.tbNavigate.addAction(action)

        self.httpsicon = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tbNavigate.addWidget(self.httpsicon)

        self.addressbar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.addressbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.tbNavigate.addWidget(self.addressbar)
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlBar)

        self.browser.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://youtube.com"))
        global_settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()

        for attr in (
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled,
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled,
        ):
            global_settings.setAttribute(attr, True)
        self.browser.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(self.FullscreenRequest)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def navigateHome(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def navigate_to_url(self):
        q = QtCore.QUrl(self.addressbar.text())
        if not q.scheme():
            q.setScheme("https")
        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QUrl)
    def update_urlBar(self, url):
        pixmap = (
            QtGui.QPixmap("icone/ssl.png")
            if url.scheme() == "https"
            else QtGui.QPixmap("icone/lock.png")
        )
        self.httpsicon.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.addressbar.setText(url.toString())
        self.addressbar.setCursorPosition(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWebEngineFullScreenRequest")
    def FullscreenRequest(self, request):
        request.accept()
        if request.toggleOn():
            self.browser.setParent(None)
            self.browser.showFullScreen()
        else:
            self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
            self.browser.showNormal()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]